# A functional $f\in X^{\star}$, $f\neq 0$ attains norm iff $f(B_{x})$ is closed.

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, operator-theory

> A functional $f\in X^{\star}$ (where $X^{\star}$ is the dual space of a normed space $X$), $f\neq 0$ attains norm if and only if $f(B_{X})$ is closed, where $B_{X}:=\{x\in X:||x||\leq 1\}$.

I write here my attempt... I'm not sure if I am think it in the right way, or if it exists a more straightforward path in proving it...:

I know that $f(B_{X})=\{f(x):||x||\leq 1\}$ is a connected set in $\mathbb{K}$. I am considering that $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$. Let's first consider $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$: then $f(B_{X})$ is an interval in $\mathbb{R}$, with one of the four following forms:
$$\left[\displaystyle\inf f(B_{X}),\sup f(B_{X})\right], \left(\displaystyle\inf f(B_{X}),\sup f(B_{X})\right),\left[\displaystyle\inf f(B_{X}),\sup f(B_{X})\right),\left(\displaystyle\inf f(B_{X}),\sup f(B_{X})\right]$$

As $-\displaystyle\sup f(-B_{X})=-\sup f(B_{X})=\displaystyle\inf f(B_{X})$, we have that, really, the only possible two options are:
$$
\left[\displaystyle-\sup f(B_{X}),\sup f(B_{X})\right], \left(\displaystyle-\sup f(B_{X}),\sup f(B_{X})\right)
$$
Then, if $f(B_{X})$ is closed, we must have the first option (the closed interval), and then, we would have that there is $x\in B_{X}$ such that $\sup f(B_{X})=f(x)$, i.e., the norm is attained, as $\sup f(B_{X})=\displaystyle\sup_{||x||\leq 1} f(x)$. Reciprocally, we would have the other implication.

If $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$, $f(B_{X})$ could take, taking in consideration everything I have written, the two following forms:
$$\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}: |\lambda|\leq ||f||\}, \{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}: |\lambda|<||f||\}$$
And again, we would have that there is $x\in B_{X}$ such that $\sup f(B_{X})=f(x)$, i.e., the norm is attained, as $\sup f(B_{X})=\displaystyle\sup_{||x||\leq 1} f(x)$, and reciprocally, we would have the other implication. This last step in expressing $f(B_{X})$ as $\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}: |\lambda|\leq||f||\}$ or $\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}: |\lambda|<||f||\}$ lies in the fact that, if I take $\lambda\in f(B_{X})$,
$e^{i\theta}\lambda$ (i.e., every rotation of $\lambda$), is in fact in $f(B_{X})$, as $||\lambda||=||e^{i\theta}\lambda||\leq 1$, and $e^{i\theta}\lambda=f(e^{i\theta}\lambda)$.

Comment: Hi, What does "f attains norm" mean? Does it mean there exists a $x$ s.t. $f(x)=||x||$?

Comment: @PNDas Not quite. It means: there is an $x\in B_X$ such that $|f(x)|=\|f\|$. This $x$ is necessarily on the surface sphere $\{x:\|x\|=1\}$. We can have $f(x)=\|f\|$, too. This is like 'attaining a maximum'

Comment: Ah, thanks @FShrike.

Comment: rubikman, your proof seems correct to me for the case $\Bbb K=\Bbb R$. You might want to justify $f(B_x)$ being the open/closed ball in more detail for $\Bbb K=\Bbb C$

Comment: Thanks, @FShrike! I will try to write it more detailed, thank you.